# Am I supposed to be able to see the AdWords conversion tag when using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-ads, google-tag-manager

I have Google Tag Manager installed and I see it in the source and in Google Tag Assistant. I added an AdWords conversion tracking goal. I input the conversion id and conversion label into Google Tag Manager and set the trigger to 'page path starts with' `/welcome`, and published the changes. I reloaded the welcome page but I don't see the AdWords conversion tracking code in the source, nor in Google Tag Assistant. I tried searching the source for the conversion id and conversion label but could not find them. I thought Google Tag Manage would use JavaScript to insert the AdWords tag into the document. Should I be able to see the conversion tracking code?

Comment: It was because of uBlock Origin. Yet no block messages in the network tab or console tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of uBlock Origin. Yet no block messages in the network tab or console tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already solved it?

You should find your tag's code amidst other GTM code in your gtm.js file. You can use CTRL + SHIFT + F in your console to do a wide file search.

However, I'd recommend you check your Network tab to confirm and validate that the hit is being properly sent.

Comment: Yes. It was because of uBlock Origin, even though there was no error in Network tab or console tab.